# Creating calculation that uses data from same field, but from different survey submission, using Survey123

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, arcgis-survey123

I need to create a survey for a Field Technician to use during a groundwater sampling event, but I can't figure out if the one section of it is at all possible using Survey123.

Every day for a few weeks, a field tech will be taking readings of discharge through a well and converting it into the average discharge per day. We normally just use a field notebook and do it by hand, but my boss wants me to create a form to do all the work and calculations for us.

The first part of the form would be the Discharge Flow Meter Totalizer (gallons) which would just be a simple integer input taken directly from the Totalizer reading. The next step would be inputting the Days Since Last Flow Meter Reading, which is another simple input integer.

The next step is where I am having issues. The next step is a calculation to figure out Average Discharge Flow Rate (GDP). This is found by taking your Discharge Flow Meter Totalizer (gal) reading, subtracting the previous Discharge Flow meter Totalizer (gal) reading from it, and then dividing that number by the Days Since Last Flow Meter Reading.

How do I set-up a form so the techs do not have to do the math on their own?

Can I pull the previous submission from Discharge Flow Meter Totalizer?

Would I have to edit the form every day to add the previous Discharge Flow Meter Totalizer so the equation works?

This form could make things a lot easier if I can figure it out, instead of writing dozens of submissions in a field notebook and then creating an Excel file out of those submissions.

Comment: I'd love to be able to pull data from AGOL but I don't think its possible.  It would be nice to see the average daily flow calculated in the form, but is it really necessary?  Do subsequent questions depend it? If the survey is just running for "a few weeks" could you do the calculation afterwards?